# Google Store Api level and App Updates OS requirements

Tags: android, react-native

To be short with it not long ago I updated my app to level 33 as requested and made my app require Android 12 and above even though I have users with lower OS who can't update the app anymore.

But I've seen the whole store and many apps still have low OS requirements did I do something wrong? Was I not meant to make it 12 and above?

And if not how to revert it?

```
buildscript {
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
    minSdkVersion = 33
    compileSdkVersion = 33
    targetSdkVersion = 33
    kotlinVersion = "1.8.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: Show snippet of your min, target etc, versions from build.gradle.

Comment: @Pawel it's working correctly this isn't my problem my problem is that should I make my min requirements OS 12 and above?

Comment: AFAIK google never forced min api to be increased on the store, as long as you are comfortable supporting them you can keep it unchanged. It's only the target API that gets bumped up every year.

Comment: @Pawel Thank you so much if you want to post it as an answer please do so I can accept it

Comment: @Pawel one more question should I also increase the compile Sdk? or just the target

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Pawel answered my question and it was fixed
"AFAIK google never forced min api to be increased on the store, as long as you are comfortable supporting them you can keep it unchanged. It's only the target API that gets bumped up every year."

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
        kotlinVersion = "1.8.0"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you've set your minSdkVersion to 33. This means that your app will only run on devices that are running Android 12 and above. If your users are using devices with lower versions of Android, they won't be able to update or install your app.

If you want to support devices with lower versions of Android, you can lower your minSdkVersion. The minSdkVersion is the lowest version of Android that your app supports. For example, if you want to support devices down to Android 6.0, you would set your minSdkVersion to 23.

Here's how you can modify your build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 23
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
        kotlinVersion = "1.8.0"
    }
}
```

Remember, setting a lower minSdkVersion means you'll need to ensure your app is compatible with older versions of Android. You may need to check in your code to handle APIs that were added in later versions of Android.

After making these changes, you'll need to rebuild your app and submit the updated APK to the Google Play Store. Your users with lower OS versions should then be able to update the app.